# custom libindicator icon is not displayed

Tags: indicator, icons, gtk, application-development, notification

I want to change the statusicon of my own little reminder program.
Currently I am using **GTK.StatusIcon** but I want to use a **ApplicationIndicator**.

Therefore I created an own Icon and moved it to:

```
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22
```

It is named indicator-notify.svg

Heres the code for the icon.

```
ind = appindicator.Indicator ("notify",
                          "indicator-notify",
                          appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
ind.set_status (appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
```

This Icon is *not* displayed. Although every other icon from this folder is.

What did I miss? Is there maybe the need to "register" the icon in GTK ?

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command:

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/
```

That will update the icon cache for the ubuntu-mono-dark theme, which should solve your problem.